# How to login with VPN using expect

Tags: bash, expect

I'm new to expect and I want to use expect to log in to a VPN. I have picked up pieces of code from the forums but I still can't get it to work. It fails to send my root password. Is the syntax-correct. Below is an example of the commands I'm running manually to login to the 
VPN. Thank you in advance.

```
sudo openvpn 'US California.ovpn'
sudo] password for tony:password

Enter Auth Username: user
Enter Auth Password: password
```

The expect script:

```
set vpnuser "user"
set vpnpassword "password"
set rootpassword "password9010"
spawn sudo openvpn 'US California.ovpn'
expect "*ssword: " 
send "$rootpassword\r" #mysetver password to login as root
expect "Enter Auth Username:\r:"
send "$vpnuser"
expect "Enter Auth Password:\r"
send "$vpnpassword"
```

Comment: expect comes with autoexpect. run `autoexpect sudo openvpn 'US California.ovpn'` and compare the resulted script with the one you have.

Comment: @paninidicuaro: What happens if you put a 1-sec sleep before sending the root password?

Comment: Thank you user1934428 this was really useful info. I was able to get some syntax from the file generated. For example, I change 'US California.ovpn' to  {US California.ovpn}, and I no longer received error messages.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the prompt you are getting:

```
sudo openvpn 'US California.ovpn'
sudo] password for tony:password

Enter Auth Username: user
Enter Auth Password: password
```

Then you are expecting wrong after spawn since above also says `for tony`
You need to write `expect "*password*:"`

Similarly you should write other expect like this:
`expect "Enter Auth Username: "` no need to put \r: 
Also 
`expect "Enter Auth Password: "`

So code becomes:

```
set vpnuser "user"
set vpnpassword "password"
set rootpassword "password9010"
spawn sudo openvpn 'US California.ovpn'
expect "*password*:" 
send "$rootpassword\r" #mysetver password to login as root
expect "Enter Auth Username: "
send "$vpnuser\r"
expect "Enter Auth Password: "
send "$vpnpassword\r"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, Tarique your example helped me. For some reason when it did not want to send my password and I had to do the following.  Any idea why                                                                                                   ```expect "Enter Auth Password:"
sleep 5
send "$vpnpassword\r"
send -- "D"
expect -exact "*"
send -- "a"
expect -exact "*"
send -- "t"
expect -exact "*"
send -- "a"
expect -exact "*"
send -- "1"
expect -exact "*"
send -- "2"
expect -exact "*"